# Swift uipickerview font

Tags: xcode, swift, uipickerview

I'm trying to change the font of the rows in a UIPickerView and using the following code.  No matter what I do I am getting errors and have exhausted about every option.  I'm almost at the point where I think it is an Xcode defect.  Any ideas

```
func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, attributedTitleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> NSAttributedString? {

    let fontAttributes = [NSFontAttributeName: UIFont(name: "Verdana", size: 5.0)]

    if (component == FOOD) {

        let title = NSMutableAttributedString(string: foodArray[row], attributes: fontAttributes)
        return title
    }
    else {
        let title = NSMutableAttributedString(string: foodArray[row], attributes: fontAttributes)
        return title

   }
}
```

Comment: What errors are you getting?

Comment: I'm getting a message that there is an "Extra Argument 'string' in call

Answer (score 2):

After an exchange with Apple I have code that actually works here is an example.  What you have to do is implement the viewForRow function, here is a working example

```
func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, viewForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int, reusingView view: UIView!) -> UIView {

    var myString = view as UILabel!

    var myStringLength = 0

    if( view == nil) {
        myString = UILabel()
    }
    if (component == FOOD) {
        myString.textAlignment = .Center

        let rowText = foodArray[row]

        var attributedRowText = NSMutableAttributedString(string: rowText)
        var attributedRowTextLength = attributedRowText.length

        attributedRowText.addAttribute(NSForegroundColorAttributeName, value: UIColor.blueColor(), range: NSRange(location: 0, length: attributedRowTextLength))

        attributedRowText.addAttribute(NSFontAttributeName, value: UIFont(name: "Helvetica", size: 16.0)!, range: NSRange(location: 0 ,length:attributedRowTextLength))

        myString!.attributedText = attributedRowText

        return myString
    }
    else {
        myString.textAlignment = .Center

        let rowText = prepArray[row]

        var attributedRowText = NSMutableAttributedString(string: rowText)
        var attributedRowTextLength = attributedRowText.length

        attributedRowText.addAttribute(NSForegroundColorAttributeName, value: UIColor.blueColor(), range: NSRange(location: 0, length: attributedRowTextLength))

        attributedRowText.addAttribute(NSFontAttributeName, value: UIFont(name: "Helvetica", size: 16.0)!, range: NSRange(location: 0 ,length:attributedRowTextLength))

        myString!.attributedText = attributedRowText

        return myString

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a case of poor error messages by the compiler, since Swift is still a new language.

I'm assuming `foodArray` is of type `[NSObject]`, or at least something other than `[String]`? Option-click it in Xcode to see its type if you didn't explicitly set it yourself.

Try declaring it as an array of strings:

```
let foodArray: [String] = // …
```

or

```
let foodArray = ["inferred", "as", "[String]", "from", "its", "contents"]
```

and if that's not feasible, retrieve your elements as `String`s:

```
let title = NSMutableAttributedString(string: foodArray[row] as String, attributes: fontAttributes)
```

It might not help you in this case, but when I see strange error messages like this, I've found that the easiest way to go about isolating the issue is to temporarily avoid one-liners by declaring every argument individually before passing them into the function. That strategy has helped me a lot with `UIView.animateWithDuration`.

Comment: So I got it to at least compile using the code below.  What I have now come up against is that it does not even appear that the attributedTitleForRow function has any impact at all.  I've seen some references that Apple may have disabled the code function although I can only find that in comments and not in any Apple documentation.